# How to move the browser window in Selenium 3?

Tags: java, selenium

The following code worked under older versions of Selenium but results in a timeout under Selenium 3:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(1315, 0));
```

What is the correct way of moving the browser window in Selenium 3?

Comment: The code still works, it required an update of the ChromeDriver.

Answer (score 1):

For python it is `driver.set_window_position(-1920,0)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way native way to resize, or manipulate browser windows in Selenium.

Source: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1750

The only simple way that I have seen it done in the past is what you did, using a point and setting the position.

Comment: Hi Jay, Thank you for the link, that was a good read. But you are merely repeating the question, not answering it.

Comment: Sorry about that