# Python Selenium - Move chrome to side of window

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am using Python Selenium to open chrmore. I would like to hve chrmoe on side like image below. Any easy way to get it done?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412606/how-to-move-the-browser-window-in-selenium-3

Answer (score 0):

use

```
add_argument("window-position=1000,1000")
```